# Pythonic way to generate list of strings containing a fragment from another list?

Tags: python

I've written some overly complex lambdas to do this, but I want to simplify. I basically want a list of strings that contain one fragment from a list.

Example:

```
strings = ["asdf", "foo", "bar", "food"]

frags = ["foo", "ar"]
```

Would result in `["foo", "food", "bar"]`

Something like: `[[s for s in string if f in s] for f in frags]` works in that it would make `[["foo", "food"], ["bar"]]`, but I want a single list of that stuff, which I would then list(set()) to get unique items.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> [s for s in strings if any(f in s for f in frags)]
['foo', 'bar', 'food']
```

The advantage of this approach is that [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) short-circuits, aborting as soon as it finds a match (which also means that you won't get duplicate items if more than one fragment happens to match a string).

And you can generate a `set` directly (although you don't need to unless you have duplicates in `strings`):

```
>>> {s for s in strings if any(f in s for f in frags)}
{'bar', 'food', 'foo'}
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't even think I knew about the any function.

Answer (score 1):

You can combine them easily:

```
[s for s in strings for f in frags if f in s]
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I love Python's list generator, but it takes some getting used to when it comes to syntax.

Comment: Yep. Try thinking about it in the order you would normally write a for loop, like `for s in strings: for f in frags: if f in s: ...`

Comment: This creates duplicate items if more than one fragment matches a string.